# Is F# supported in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: f#, xamarin.forms

Can I write a Xamarin.Forms app in F#?

I do not see a project template for this in VS2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may not be a template, but you can use Xamarin.Forms in F#. Charles Petzold wrote a blog post on it that you might find useful:

http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2015/10/Writing-Xamarin-Forms-Apps-in-FSharp.html

Answer (score 1):

I see this F# Xamarin project:

[image]

Comment: Yes. However, I do not see a Xamarin.Forms project.

Comment: probably it isn't available for Starter Edition: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34107378/240564